# Bash on Windows configuration to copy when selecting text and paste with Shift+Insert

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just installed the ubuntu bash capability on my windows machine. How do I configure my terminal to copy text only by selecting it? Right now I have to do right click on the selected text in order to copy it.

I tried looking for some information on how to paste text in the terminal using the keyboard but so far nothing has worked (currently pasting by right clicking the mouse). I want to be able to paste text when I so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/235

Comment: To those voting to close, WSL and ubuntu on WSL is considered on topic here

Comment: So there is no current solution as of now?

Comment: @Panther It is indeed, but this question as far as I understand it is not about WSL, but rather copying text in Windows 10.

Comment: @dessert he is wanting to copy text into the ubuntu terminal / bash

Comment: [it's developed finally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845254/4023950) :    )